# How to store ` keyvalue` in the template variable

Tags: angular, angular-pipe

I am trying to use the `keyvalue` and print in template. but not able to assign with variable. what would be the correct approach here?

`<h1 let item = (data|keyvalue)>New value {{item.key}}</h1>` - not working

in my ts file there is a data:

`data = { value: 'info' };`

I can directly print this. but to know how it can be handled with `keyvalue`

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `keyvalue` pipe return an array of key-value-pairs. Only in your example the object has a single entry. Either iterate the resulting array with `*ngFor` or access the first array element like below.

```
<h1 *ngIf="(data | keyvalue)?.[0] as item">
  New value {{ item.key }}
</h1>
```